# Django, reference to model object from forms.py

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I want to custom validate a `Page` object. A `Project` has many `Page`'s.
To validate the `Page` object I need to get a reference to the `Project` object through its `pk` in `Page`.

Need to compare `start_date` field in `Project` to `start_date` field in `Page`:

```
class PageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Page

    def clean_start_date(self):
        # need to get "page.project.start_date" somehow.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `instance` property:

```
class PageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Page

    def clean_start_date(self):
        project_start_date = self.instance.project.start_date
```